# Android Switching Business Unit

Tags: mobilesdk, android, sfdcmobilesdk-android, salesforce-sdk-android

i am facing the situation that inside my Android Application the user could switch between different Business Units. Inside the Documentation for iOS there is a part for switching between Business Units (https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/sdk-implementation/business-unit-switching.html) but there is no similar Page inside the Android Documentation. 
Is there a similar way for switching the Business Unit in Android? Or is the only exercise for me to register the SDK with the new Business Unit? Is it guaranteed that i don't receive Push Messages for the "old" Business Unit after switching?

Sorry if this might be a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

You can switch to a different business unit be simply calling the MarketingCloudSdk's `init` method with the credentials of the new business unit.  This will signal to the SDK to clean up the existing configuration and re-initialize with the new configuration.

There is **no** guarantee that the device will not still receive push messages from the previous business unit (this includes iOS) as the device and push token will be associated with both business units in the Marketing Cloud.  You could manage this by setting/removing an attribute/tag in the registration before/after switching business units.  This value could then be used to include/exclude certain devices from receiving a push message.